# Enabling .htaccess ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to enable my .htaccess in Ubuntu 16.04, so I enabled a2enmod with:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Also I've added the following lines in etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Also I've added the following lines in etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
```

After this all I've restarted Apache2, the server but no result yet.. Any clear answer on how to enable .htaccess to remove the .php extension? Thanks already!

---

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: With `MultiViews` enabled, you shouldn't need to use `mod_rewrite` just to hide the file extension. It should already _"just work"_

Comment: It doesn't I've tried it already ;/

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried? What URL are you attempting to access? What is the URL of the PHP script it should execute?

Comment: Just the server IP /index.php but I want all urls to be without a .php

Comment: So you're trying `http://<server-ip>/index`?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: So what do you get? A 404 error? Something else? Are there any other files or directories named "index", eg `index.html`?

Comment: Or is it possible with PHP?

Comment: Just a 404 error

Comment: And `http://<server-ip>/index.php` works fine?

Comment: yes it does, just not without the .php extension

Comment: It works fine for me. So what's in your `.htaccess` file? Try removing that file and try again.

Comment: I'll try everything again. I'll let you know! Thanks for helping me, really appreciate it.

Comment: What do I put in my .htaccess to remove .php the right way?

Comment: Still not working with this code in my .htaccess RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: It's only my opinion but I believe `MultiViews` is the _"right way"_ to hide file extensions in request URLs. Using URL rewriting is complete overkill

Comment: Ill post a screenshot of that multiviews page, maybe I got it in wrong here: https://gyazo.com/0897e55bdab04f76189e79567f2db0cd

Comment: Didn't I say to try removing the `.htaccess` file? You already have everything in place to access URLs without file extensions. You simply **do not need** rewrite rules

Comment: I removed the .htaccess already